# Active Directory Server and Mimikatz

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server, mimikatz

Is it possible to use mimikatz to dump plaintext passwords of users in network by injecting mimilsa into lsass in Active Directory server? Basically other than dumping SAM which contains all hashes of everyone in the AD domain, can you do anything else with mimikatz?

Answer (score 1):

Are you targeting to dump all the plaintext password of all users in AD?

As far as I know, you can use mimikatz sekurlsa module in **dumping  passwords, keys, pin codes, tickets** from the memory of **lsass** in selected workstations, not in lsass of AD Server.

Refer to this https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/module-~-sekurlsa#logonpasswords

If you want to dump all the user password hash in Domain, another thing you can do in mimikatz is DCsync which you can pull the password hash, as well as previous password hashes, it retrieves the password hashes from the **NTDS.DIT**. DSsync requires a privileged account with domain replication rights.

Refer to this link: https://adsecurity.org/?p=1729